# Request for a paper by Wightman and Gårding

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, schwartz-distributions, paper-request

I am looking for a pdf version of the following paper

A. Wightman and L. Gårding, Fields as operator-valued distributions in
relativistic quantum theory, Arkiv för Fysik 28 (1964), 129–189.

Does anyone have it?

Comment: If you're OK with effectively equivalent content (plus more), you can find it in Ch.3 of the much more readily available monograph _PCT, spin, statistics and all that_ by Streater & Wightman (1964). I imagine that the separate Wightman-Gårding article only has historical interest.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/pctspinstatistic0000stre